# Android Studio Showing all Red errors But all the codes are ok?

Tags: android, android-studio

[[image: [1]]

Android Studio Showing all Red errors But all the codes seems to be OK? In this image shown AppCompatActivity and all imported  files. what should I do now ??

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: your gradle sync isn't complete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, clean your project and rebuild again. If your issue is not still not resolved the then open the build.gradle(Module:app) file and try to update your appcompat library using this line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
```

version number (25.1.1) is different according to your targetSdkVersion.